# Purchasing a router for home movie streaming No ISP

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

The idea is to purchase a router for a home without an ISP (no ISP for at least a year) and use the router to create a network whereby residents with 802.11 g/n/b tablets and phones can connect to it to stream movies and view files such as photos located on an external hdd connected to the router by USB (2.0). Basically, I will be trying to set up a simple NAS.

My hestitation and reason for this post:

1. No ISP, so no modem. A salesperson I spoke to laughed at me saying an ISP connection is a must and suggested I look at docking stations instead.
2. The router will eventually be used to connect to the internet in about a year when the ISP becomes available to us at that address.
3. The home has no computer, I will be configuring the router elsewhere and bringing it in already configured.
4. The hdd will connect to the new router by USB. I want to avoid video playback stuttering, lag, garble, etc. Is there a cause for concern? Is a wifi bandwidth 300 Mbps sufficient?
5. Will the hdd get enough power from the router?
6. Is there anything else I should know about?

Comment: That sales person is...(censored) (censored) (censored). No ISP connection is needed to form a network. Period. And a docking station does something quite different from an access point, so he/she seems to have no technical knowledge in this field at all.

Comment: @Hennes Thank you for confirming that. I suspected routers can serve more than one purpose, independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Salespersons are known for not knowing a thing. You could pick nearly any "wireless router" in existence and use it offline. (Most of them don't contain a 'modem' at all either, only having an Ethernet port for the uplink.)

   That said, I would be careful with the new "app-managed" hardware from Google and such – but even those should usually have an offline mode.
2. That shouldn't be a problem, although it depends on what hardware the ISP will provide later. (The search keyword is "why not to stack routers" – since you have your own router, you might want to configure the ISP-provided modem to not act as one.)
3. Shouldn't be a problem for now (after all, if there is no ISP, then there are no location-specific settings – other than the Wi-Fi channel/frequency.) However, see also #2.
4. The "300 Mbps" figure is only *raw* wireless throughput of 802.11n (in 40 MHz mode and with two streams *and* in perfect conditions) – the actual data transfer speeds will be *much* lower than that. I'd expect 20–60 Mbps, to be honest.

   On the other hand, a HD stream only needs about 4–6 Mbps. If you can watch YouTube or Netflix over a slow Internet connection, then you should be able to watch the same video locally just fine. (Disclaimer: I'm definitely *not* an expert in this regard.)
5. The router itself is AC-powered, so yes, I would assume that it can provide the same amount of power as a regular PC would. (In fact, my *phone* can supply enough power to a 2.5" HD.) That said, most 3.5" disks actually come with their own external power supplies since USB isn't enough for them either way.
6. You don't have to rely on *one* device for this – if the Wi-Fi coverage isn't good enough, you can always buy a standalone AP (access point, sometimes marketed as "extender") and connect it to the router via Ethernet.

---

If you want to get technical, it *could* be said that a router is useless without being in between of at least two networks (e.g. LAN and Internet), but that doesn't matter here since you're *not* really buying the router for its IP routing features anyway. Instead you're buying it for the extras that usually come bundled – namely, a Wi-Fi AP, a DHCP server, and various USB media sharing software. None of these require an Internet connection of any sort.

Comment: Not to mention, having your entire home network go down if your ISP messed up would be pointless. And ISPs mess up